# Value is not showing on PhoneInput UI in react-native after inserting the number

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have used `react-native-phone-number-input` npm package to insert phoneNumber based on Country. But When I click on the number then the value is not shown in UI as mentioned attached screenshot.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-number-input';

const ComPhoneInput = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [phoneValue, setPhoneValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.phoneContainerStyle}>
      <PhoneInput
        defaultValue={phoneNumber}
        defaultCode="BD"
        placeholder="01770019346"
        onChangeFormattedText={inputValue => {
          setPhoneNumber(inputValue);
        }}
        onChangeText={pValue => {
          setPhoneValue(pValue);
        }}
        containerStyle={styles.phoneMainStyle}
        textContainerStyle={styles.phoneTextMainStyle}
        textInputStyle={styles.phoneTextStyle}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ComPhoneInput;
```

**Note:** *Here is the ScreenShoot. Please check and if you have an idea, please help me with your valuable guideline. Advanced Thanks.*

[image: Screenshot of UI]

Comment: is this issue exists in android or ios? or both? I just tested your code on an ios device and it is working.

Comment: Hello Harsh, I have faced this on Android in Ubuntu 22.04 OS.

If it's working on iOS then what would be the issue from my side? It's confusing.

Comment: I've just verified it in android too, and it works fine there. 
There could be a few possibilities, probably a version issue, Can you check if you have the latest version? Also if you have latest, I suggest to test in a real device to get it verified.

Comment: Can you share your whole page component files code so I can debug more and check the provided component works totally fine? It'll be easier to debug. 
Also, there is the possibility that it is typing into the input but due to design it is not visible, So I guess style property would be great if you can provide them.

Comment: I checked that the value is perfectly inserted but it doesn't show in UI. What would be the issue?

Comment: This is your UI issue. If you can provide me with the style of this component, I can debug it.

Comment: Wait I am sharing with you, brother.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254935/discussion-between-harsh-nahta-and-imdadul-haque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your styling,
To get this fixed, add height property to the following styles :

```
 phoneMainStyle: {
    // containerStyle
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: COLOR_CONST.DARK_GREEN,
    color: COLOR_CONST.WHITE,
  },
  phoneTextStyle: {
    // textInputStyle
    color: COLOR_CONST.WHITE,
    height: 50,
  },
```

Once you add the height to these 2 styles, your issues will be fixed.

Here the problem was with the height of the input container, you have reduced the height of the external due to the inner height getting cut off.

Here is the output now :

[image]

Let me know if you face any other issues. Happy to help :)